# Closing Dialog after New Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

i have an app to read nfc tags and as long as the nfc tag 
is not placed near the mobile phone i show a progress dialog
with a small animation and the advice to the user to place 
the nfc tag close to the mobile phone.

However.. on a new Intent (in my cas nfc intent) i want the
dialog to close automatically and to start a new activity.

until now i did that:

```
    Intent newIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), NFCResultActivity.class);
    newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    this.startActivity(newIntent);
    this.finish();
```

So the current activity gets deleted (FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) and the new
activity is started. But that seems not to be very clean because i get the
following error message:

```
11-02 15:12:49.375: E/WindowManager(25579): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity 
de.MyActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41ec5db0 V.E..... R......D 0,0-729,324} 
that was originally added here
```

So how can i do it clean?

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred because your dialog is shown after the activity is destroyed. Dismiss the dialog before you start the new activity :

```
    myDialog.dismiss();
    Intent newIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), NFCResultActivity.class);
    newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    this.startActivity(newIntent);
    this.finish();
```

Or call the `myDialog.dismiss();` in the `onPause` so the dialog will be dismissed when the activity is destroyed.

Comment: Yes sure but the problem is that the intent is not started from the current activity. i have a central activity called NFCActivity which is always called when there is a nfc intent. The activity where i show the progress dialog is another activity.

Comment: I see...sorry i never used NFC before. Do you think you can use startactivityforresult to fix this?

Comment: wait..so the dialog is in the NFCActivity?

Comment: unfortunately not. maybe it is possible to get the current activity when the intent is triggered? No. The Dialog is in my NFC Result activity. To explain it: You can manually call the NFC Result Activity but when there is no nfc tag to read i show the progress dialog to advice the user to place the tag. but now when he places the tag a new intent is triggered to my NFCActivity. The NFCActivity then calls a new NFCResultActivity with the result of the nfc tag.